# WCF Test client not loading the Service

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0

Recently I developed a wcf service.
It was working fine till yesterday . I was able to test it
using VS2010 in built WCF Test client.
Since Yesterday I am not able to see my service in WCF Test client.
When I press F5 it opens the Wcf test client window and at the bottom 
it shows Servie added successfully. But it doesn't load any service.
I tried to add it manually from file/add service, still it doesn't load.
What could be the problem.
I really appreciate your help.
Here is my Web.config.

---

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <bindings/>
    <client/>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="myproj.ServiceBehavior" name="myproj.Service">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="myproj.IService" behaviorConfiguration="REST">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="REST">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="myproj.ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're using the `webHttpBinding` for a REST-style WCF service.

The WCF Test Client is a **SOAP** test application - it works against SOAP web services (basically anything **but** the `webHttpBinding`, in WCF).

For REST services, just browse to the service URL and invoke your REST service that way.

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way I can Invoke the Test client for a REST application?

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat: for REST, you need to use another tool - something like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/get-fiddler). The WCF Test Client does ***NOT*** work for REST

Comment: @marc_s..
I am a newbie in .NET 
Is there any problem with using wcf service application to host a server in IIS, if yes what? Is there any advantage for using a wcf service library? How does WCF service library work in Cassini by pressing F5 but I cannot host it in the IIS directly, considering the fact that Cassini is used for testing before using in IIS, why does this occur? 
Please provide me with some insight on this.

Comment: Can you please get me your email id?

Comment: How do I stop this service from auto-opening in the WCF Test Client then?